Azure function New Relic APM Service Not Creating
I'm working with an Azure Function using the in-process model, configured with .NET 8 and Function version 4. I've implemented Serilog with New Relic ingestion and am successfully receiving logs. However, the APM service isn't being created in New Relic. Could someone clarify if migrating the Azure Function from the in-process model to the isolated model is necessary to enable New Relic APM services?
    "CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING": "1",
"CORECLR_PROFILER": "{36032161-FFC0-4B61-B559-F6C5D41BAE5A}",
"CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH": "",
"CORECLR_NEWRELIC_HOME": "",
"NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY": "",
"NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME": "",
"NEW_RELIC_APPLICATION_LOGGING_ENABLED": ""

Register serilog with rew relic
public static void RegisterSerilog(AppSettings settings)
{ 
// Set up Serilog configuration
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is(Enum.Parse<LogEventLevel> 
(settings.LoggerSettings.NewRelicSettings.MinimumLogLevel, true)) // Read log 
 level from settings
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithNewRelicLogsInContext()
    .WriteTo.NewRelicLogs( // Write to New Relic Logs
        endpointUrl: settings.LoggerSettings.NewRelicSettings.EndpointUrl,
        applicationName: settings.LoggerSettings.NewRelicSettings.ApplicationName,
        licenseKey: settings.LoggerSettings.NewRelicSettings.LicenseKey)
    .CreateLogger();
}


Are you getting any error while enabling New Relic APM service in isolated function?

Hello @IkhtesamAfrin, my azure function is in process model, I do not want to migrate that to isolation model. So, the question is can we implement new relic APM service without migrating to isolation model? Because the way I tried implementing its not working.
